# Increasing the search query limit (Apache Solr)

Tags: 7, views, search

We want to create a search page with Apache Solr with an increased query limit. I was reading that using `hook_search_execute` was not a recommended way to do this.

Is this statement correct? What would be the recommended way to go about this?

Apache Solr Views module?

Some other solution?

The page absolutely has to have more than 10 search results, and no pager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do that programatically, you can implement `hook_apachesolr_query_alter()` to play with the [`rows`](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters#rows) parameter :

```
function yourmodule_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
  // Increase the number of results per query
  $query->replaceParam('rows', 50);
}
```

Note : To disable the pager you can set a very very large number of rows, but it may impact performance. In this case you may prefer to bypass the pager at another level (for example in a preprocess function) and go with a more reasonable `rows` value.

Comment: Actually using ```hook_apachesolr_query_prepare``` will cause the pager to also use the correct number of rows.

Answer (score 1):

There is apparently a setting for this in the Apache Solr module itself.

Go to the specific search that you want to modify, and edit the "Advanced Search Page Options" value.